# Using JavaScript functions as "classes": What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript

Here's my JavaScript "class" so far:

```
    function snake(C, C_h, C_w)
    {

            this.linkSize = 10; // size of a snake unit, in pixels

            /* On instantiation, the snake direction is down and has 1 link */
            this.dy = this.linkSize;
            this.dx = 0;
            this.link = C.rect(C_h/2, C_w/2, this.linkSize, this.linkSize);
            this.link.attr("fill", "#d7a900");
            this.body = [link];

            /* Event listener for changing the direction of the
               snake with arrow keys on the keyboard
            */
            this.redirect = function(dirnum)
            {
                switch (dirnum)
                {
                    /*
                        dirnum corresponds to
                        1 ---> right
                        2 ---> down
                        3 ---> left
                        4 ---> up
                    */
                    case 1: 
                        this.dx = this.linkSize;
                        this.dy = 0;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        this.dx = 0;
                        this.dy = this.linkSize;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        this.dx = -this.linkSize;
                        this.dy = 0;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        this.dx = -this.linkSize;
                        this.dy = 0;
                        break;

                    default: // never happens
                        break;
                }

            }
            this.move = function()
            {
                /*
                    ///// 
                */

                var temp = body[0];
                body[0].translate(this.dx, this.dy);
                for (var i = 1, j = body.length; i < j; ++i)
                {
                    body[i] = temp;
                    temp = body[i];
                }
            }

            setInterval(this.move());
    }
```

I have 2 problems that are being reported in my Google Chrome console:

- **Uncaught ReferenceError: link is not defined** (on the `this.link.attr("fill", "#d7a900");` line).
- `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` (whenever I press an arrow key)

Does anyone have some insight into why these problems are occurring? Am I using the `this.` keyword correctly?

Comment: And what is `C`?  If it's undefined, then `link` is undefined...

Comment: What exactly does `C.rect` return?

Comment: C is a Raphael object (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: link is not defined` does mean that the call to `C.rect()` returns `undefined` or `null`.

"`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` (whenever I press an arrow key)"

There is no event handling visible in your code, but this might just be a follow-up error.

Triple check (using `console.log`) that `C` was correctly passed into the function and what the return value of `C.rect()` actually is.